# putting form for new inside other view from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have created an app which has a user, user can have many players and each player can have many abilities. Now in my player show view, I can see information about a player and his abilities, but also I want to have a form for creating/updating abilities for that player. How do I implement a view from abilities controller to player show view so i can create/edit and delete his abilities directly from there via ajax? I was thinking about making new.html.erb from abilities a partial and then render it into show.html.erb but what do I put in form_for so that rails knows that its supposed to communicate with different model and controller? Whats the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no problem in adding the form_for for the associated model(Ability) in show of Player. You can make a partial of the form, and render it for all its abilities.

In controller,

```
@abilities = @player.abilities
```

And in show,

```
#Some code to show player details
<% @abilities.each do |ability| %>
<%= render 'ability', ability: ability%> #Pass local variable ability to partial
<% end %>
```

And make partial using form_for tag with AJAX in init to update the information. Also, you can define 'action' of form_for tag using

```
form_for(ability,:url => url_for(:controller => 'abilities', :action => 'update')
```

You can place the partial of ability in abilities folder corresponding to Abilities Controller and give its relative path in the above render statement as:

```
<%= render '/abilities/ability', ability: ability %>
```